# How to resize photos in React-slick costompaging

Tags: reactjs, slick.js, lib

I'm a novice front-end developer

Do you know how to resize photos in React Slick's custom paging mode?

**Problem**
I can't resize the photos I select other than slides.

**trying**
I'm doing some styling that involves CSS, so I'm using
(Using a style component)

**My code**

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import styled from "styled-components";

import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export default function CenterMode() {
  const settings = {
    customPaging: function (i: number) {
      return <SelectImageBox src={`/assets/abstract0${i + 1}.png`} />;
    },
    dots: true,
    dotsClass: "slick-dots slick-thumb",
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomSlider {...settings}>
        <div>
          <Images src={"/assets/abstract01.png"} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Images src={"/assets/abstract02.png"} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Images src={"/assets/abstract03.png"} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Images src={"/assets/abstract04.png"} />
        </div>
      </CustomSlider>
    </div>
  );
}

const CustomSlider = styled(Slider)`
  .slick-dots.slick-thumb {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: black;
  }
`;

const SelectImageBox = styled.img``;

const Images = styled.img`
  width: 428px;
  height: 420px;
`;
```

**and My Screenshot**
[image]

**What I want**
Resize the photo in px

thank you! i want you to be happy! and help me plase..ㅠㅠ